# ExtJS 6 drag grid columns to toolbar

Tags: extjs

I'm making first steps in new ExtJS 6 framework. I have a grid which loads data with variable columns. The user should be able to drag specific columns to the grid toolbar for further processing.

I found Ext.ux.ToolbarDroppable which seems to be the right approach for the task. My toolbar looks like this:

```
tbar: {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tbtext',
        text: 'Proceed with following columns:'
    }],
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.ux.ToolbarDroppable', {createItem: function(data) {
            return Ext.create('Ext.Button', {text: data.text});
        }})
    ]
}
```

The grid columns can be dragged and dropped in the grid header to reorder the columns but I cannot figure out the steps to make them droppable in the toolbar. The toolbar plugin has a method called **addDDGroup()** to define a drag/drop group but I can't find where this group is defined in the column config.

Who knows how to make the grid columns be droppable into the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Ext.grid.column.Column.[initDraggable()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/Column2.html#Ext-grid-column-Column-method-initDraggable):

```
// Header does not use the typical ComponentDraggable class and therefore we
// override this with an emptyFn. It is controlled at the HeaderDragZone.
```

helped me to find Ext.grid.header.[DragZone](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.header.DragZone).[getDDGroup()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/DragZone2.html#Ext-grid-header-DragZone-method-getDDGroup).

You can try whether using the same ddgroup works; but I can guarantee for nothing, since

> Header does not use the typical ComponentDraggable class